# Convert SQL to Linq with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, .net-core, repository-pattern

I am using .NET Core 2.2, EF Core, C# and SQL Server 2017.
I am not able to translate the query I need to Linq.

This is the query I need to convert:

```
SELECT      TOP 5
            p.Id, 
            p.Title, 
            AVG(q.RatingValue) AvgRating
FROM        Movies AS p
INNER JOIN  Ratings AS q ON p.Id = q.MovieId
GROUP BY    p.Id, p.Title
ORDER BY    AvgRating DESC, p.Title ASC
```

The idea of the previous query is to get the Top 5 movies according to the Avg rating, ordering it by the highest average first, and in case of same average order alphabetically.

So far this is my query that makes the join, but then still missing: the group by, average, and ordering:

```
public class MovieRepository : IMovieRepository
{
    private readonly MovieDbContext _moviesDbContext;
    public MovieRepository(MovieDbContext moviesDbContext)
    {
        _moviesDbContext = moviesDbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Movie> GetTopFive()
    {
        var result = _moviesDbContext.Movies.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(5).
                     Include(x => x.Ratings);

        return result;
    }
}
```

And these are the entities:

```
 public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int YearOfRelease { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public int RunningTime { get; set; }
    public IList<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
}

public class Rating
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public decimal RatingValue { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to use Linqer tool also to convert my query to Linq, but it was not working.

I will appreciate any help to convert that query to LINQ for the method "GetTopFive".

Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting top rated 5 or just top 5?

Comment: Top rated 5. So 1 movie could have one or more rows in the rating table. By example, 10 users could rate Terminator 1, if, for this movie, the average of those rating is the maximum compared with other movies, should be shown first.

Comment: Wait! I am updating the answer

Comment: consider also grouping the rows of the Rating and get the Avg.

Comment: Yeh! but I am trying a different solution.

Comment: Check my answer! I have update the answer. I have checked it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
var data = _moviesDbContext.Movies.Include(x => x.Ratings)
            .Select(x => new {
                Id = x.Id,
                Title = x.Title,
                Average = (int?)x.Ratings.Average(y => y.RatingValue)
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Average).ThenBy(x => x.Title).Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: Your previous query was right. This will throw `Sequence contains no elements.` if movie have no rating yet! Apart from this, there is another problem in this query. You didn't use `.Include(m => m.Ratings)`.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Thanks for comment. I am also new to linq and lambda. I am querying Movie Table directly so don't u think in table Movie using .GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Title }) has no significance that's why I removed it. Also Including Rating data here is not required as he wants only average rating that will be calculated in DB only..??

Comment: Without Include Ratings will be null! Hence will throw exception.

Comment: The `Include` isn't necessary because `x.Ratings` is already part of the query. The only thing is that it should be `(int?)x.Ratings.Average(y => y.RatingValue)` so movies without rating can have a `null` value. Then I think it should be correct, demonstrating that a LINQ groupby isn't necessary. @MarcosF8 It would be nice to have a bit more feedback than "not working" :).

Comment: @GertArnold I agree

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<Movie> GetTopFive()
{
    var result = _moviesDbContext.Ratings.GroupBy(r => r.MovieId).Select(group => new
        {
            MovieId = group.Key,
            MovieTitle = group.Select(g => g.Movie.Title).FirstOrDefault(),
            AvgRating = group.Average(g => g.RatingValue)
        }).OrderByDescending(s => s.AvgRating).Take(5).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

This will exclude the movies having no ratings.

But if you do as follows (as artista_14's answer):

```
public IEnumerable<Movie> GetTopFive()
{
    var result = _moviesDbContext.Movies.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Title })
        .Select(x => new {
            Id = x.Key.Id,
            Title = x.Key.Title,
            Average = x.Average(y => y.Ratings.Sum(z => z.RatingValue))
    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Average).ThenBy(x => x.Title).Take(5).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

this will include the movies having no ratings also.

Note: I see your `Rating` model class does not contain any `Movie` navigation property. Please add this as follows:

```
public class Rating
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public decimal RatingValue { get; set; }

    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if it works or not! If not then please let me know the error message.

Comment: I got an error saying: System.ArgumentException: 'At least one object must implement IComparable.'

Comment: Oh! I suspect that! Wait please!

Comment: If your controller is API Controller than ensure that on top of your controller `[Produces("application/json")]` attribute is present.

Comment: not working yet, getting this sql: SELECT [g.Movie0].[Id], [g.Movie0].[Title]
FROM [Movies] AS [g.Movie0]

Comment: I had to make conversion for IEnumerable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187009/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-marcosf8).

Comment: @MarcosF8 Check the chat please

Comment: Help you tomorrow please!

Comment: Thank you so much TanvirArjel, big effort trying to resolve the issue from your side, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: The query you have used is going to fail in certain circumstances as I have described in that answer's comment.

Answer (score 0):

and finally this is the code working nicely:

```
var data = _moviesDbContext.Movies.Include(x => x.Ratings)
            .Select(x => new MovieRating
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Title = x.Title,
                Average = x.Ratings.Average(y => y.RatingValue)
            }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Average).ThenBy(x => x.Title).Take(5).ToList();

        return data;
```

The problem was creating an anonymous type in the select, so this line resolves the issue: .Select(x => new MovieRating

And this is the complete code for the method and the new class I have created to map the select fields with a concrete type:

```
public class MovieRepository : IMovieRepository
{
    private readonly MovieDbContext _moviesDbContext;
    public MovieRepository(MovieDbContext moviesDbContext)
    {
        _moviesDbContext = moviesDbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Movie> GetAll()
    {
        return _moviesDbContext.Movies;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MovieRating> GetTopFive()
    {
        var result = _moviesDbContext.Movies.Include(x => x.Ratings)
                    .Select(x => new MovieRating
                    {
                        Id = x.Id,
                        Title = x.Title,
                        Average = x.Ratings.Average(y => y.RatingValue)
                    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Average).ThenBy(x => x.Title).Take(5).ToList();

        return result;
    }
}

public class MovieRating
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Average { get; set; }
}
```